# Amazon S3 bucket policy change giving access denied with full admin aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, access-denied

I have logged in to my AWS account with full admin access, I have an Amazon S3 bucket created already and it has a bucket policy.
Now I am trying to update the bucket policy but It was giving me access denied?

I am not making my bucket public, so I dont wanna uncheck block all public access which is present to my bucket configuration.

What else can I check to make that work and what could be the potential issue causing me the access denied issue with full admin account?

Comment: Can you show us the Bucket Policy? It is possible to cause this situation by adding a `Deny` statement in the bucket policy, which prohibits access, including changing the bucket policy! If this is the case, you will need to use the Root login (with an email address) to remove the bucket policy.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, sorry I cant exactly show the bucket policy but there was no deny policy at all

Comment: Can't because you get Access Denied, or simply because you do not wish to show it? If it is Access Denied, then you'll need to use the Root login to access and fix it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I cant show the policy content here, It was accessible to me and I can see the policy, but when I wish to change the policy , It was giving me access denied .